# BeanIO 2.1 Wrapped Segments

Tags: java, segment

Hello guys I am using BeanIO to write to CSV file.

I have a complex class structure that I want to output in one column. And here are the classes I am using. "Main" class is **GprsEvent**:

```
public class GprsEvent
{
    private ListOfServiceData   listOfServiceData;
    // setters and getters omitted
}

public class ListOfServiceData implements Serializable
{
    private List<ChangeOfServiceCondition> seqOf = null;
    // setters and getters omitted
}

public class ChangeOfServiceCondition implements Serializable
{
    private RatingGroupId ratingGroup = null;
    private ChargingRuleBaseName chargingRuleBaseName = null;
    private ResultCode resultCode = null;
    private LocalSequenceNumber localSequenceNumber = null;
    private TimeStamp timeOfFirstUsage = null;
    private TimeStamp timeOfLastUsage = null;
    private CallDuration timeUsage = null;
    private ServiceConditionChange serviceConditionChange = null;
    **private EPCQoSInformation qoSInformationNeg = null;** // Complex Type
    private GSNAddress servingNodeAddress = null;
    private DataVolumeGPRS datavolumeFBCUplink = null;
    private DataVolumeGPRS datavolumeFBCDownlink = null;
    private TimeStamp timeOfReport = null;
    private FailureHandlingContinue failureHandlingContinue = null;
    private ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier = null;
    private BerOctetString userLocationInformation = null;
    // setters and getters omitted
}

public class EPCQoSInformation implements Serializable
{

    public byte[] code = null;
    private BerInteger qCI = null;
    private BerInteger maxRequestedBandwithUL = null;
    private BerInteger maxRequestedBandwithDL = null;
    private BerInteger guaranteedBitrateUL = null;
    private BerInteger guaranteedBitrateDL = null;
    private BerInteger aRP = null;
    // setters and getters omitted
}
```

I have read through BeanIO documentation and found how to do what I intend: http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#AdvancedTopics - **5.8.2. Wrapped Segments**

So this is part of my beanio XML file:

```
<record class="net.atos.tools.radiation.convert.event.gprs.GprsEvent"
        name="sGWRecord" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" order="1">

    <segment name="listOfServiceData">
    <segment name="listOfServiceData" class="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.ListOfServiceData"> 
        <segment name="changeOfServiceCondition">
        <segment name="changeOfServiceCondition" class="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.ChangeOfServiceCondition" collection="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
             <field name="ratingGroup" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.RatingGroupId" />
             <field name="chargingRuleBaseName" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.ChargingRuleBaseName" />
             <field name="resultCode" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.ResultCode" />
             <field name="localSequenceNumber" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.localSequenceNumberp"/> 
             <field name="timeOfFirstUsage" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.TimeStamp"/> 
             <field name="timeOfLastUsage" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.TimeStamp"/> 
             <field name="timeUsage" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.CallDuration"/> 
             <segment name="qoSInformationNeg">
             <segment name="qoSInformationNeg" class="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.EPCQoSInformation" occursRef="timeUsage">
                    <field name="qCI" type="org.openmuc.jasn1.ber.types.BerInteger"/>
                    <field name="maxRequestedBandwithUL" type="org.openmuc.jasn1.ber.types.BerInteger"/>
                    <field name="maxRequestedBandwithDL" type="org.openmuc.jasn1.ber.types.BerInteger"/>
                    <field name="guaranteedBitrateUL" type="org.openmuc.jasn1.ber.types.BerInteger"/>
                    <field name="guaranteedBitrateDL" type="org.openmuc.jasn1.ber.types.BerInteger"/>
                    <field name="aRP" type="org.openmuc.jasn1.ber.types.BerInteger"/>
             </segment>
             </segment>
        </segment>
        </segment>
    </segment>
    </segment>  

</record>
```

I am receving the following error: **org.beanio.BeanIOConfigurationException: Invalid segment 'qoSInformationNeg', in segment 'qoSInformationNeg', in segment 'changeOfServiceCondition', in segment 'changeOfServiceCondition', in segment 'listOfServiceData', in segment 'listOfServiceData', in record 'sGWRecord', in stream 'gprs': Collection required when maxOccurs is greater than 1 and class is set**

Answer (score 0):

Okay found solution myself, problem occurs when more than one `collection="list"` are present. For example in my XML file, first list occurrence is:

```
<field name="sgsnAddressLength" type="java.lang.Integer" typeHandler="sgsnAddressLengthHandler" /> 
<field name="sgsnAddresses" type="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.GSNAddress" collection="list" occursRef="sgsnAddressLength" typeHandler="sgsnAddressesHandler" />
```

Where next list occurs after that:

```
<segment name="changesOfServiceCondition" class="net.atos.open.muc.generated.datatypes.ChangeOfServiceCondition" 
                     collection="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
```

In the field where first list occourance is present, you have to add: occursRef keyword. In my case first list name is **sgsnAddresses** and I had to add `occursRef="sgsnAddressLength"` , since **sgsnAddressLength** is the field that precedes first list occourance.